# Hide dropzone after dragSource was cancelled

Tags: jsf, drag-and-drop, richfaces, invisible

I have an `a4j:outputPanel` which is the parent for a `rich:dragSource`. Below this panel I have an invisible `rich:panel` which is my dropzone. When I start dragging the panel above the dropzone gets visible. This is done like that:

```
<h:panelGroup id="panelWrapper">
    <a4j:outputPanel onmousedown="beginDragDrop();" >
        <rich:dragSource type="type" />                           
        <h:outputText value="content" />                 
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</h:panelGroup>

<rich:panel  id="dropTargetPanelWrapper" >
    <rich:panel id="dropTargetPanel" rendered="#{bean.showDropTarget}" >
        <rich:dropTarget immediate="true" acceptedTypes="type" dropListener="#{bean.processDrop}" oncomplete="stopDragDrop();" render="panelWrapper" />     
    </rich:panel>
<rich:panel  id="dropTargetPanelWrapper" styleClass="dropTargetPanelWrapper"  >

<a4j:jsFunction name="beginDragDrop" action="#{bean.beginDragDrop}" render="dropTargetPanelWrapper" />
<a4j:jsFunction name="stopDragDrop" action="#{bean.stopDragDrop}" render="dropTargetPanelWrapper" />
```

Making the dropzone visible is done via `onmousedown="beginDragDrop();"` on the `a4j:outputPanel`. This works fine so far. When the user drags the panel to the dropzone the apropriate bean method gets called and the `oncomplete="stopDragDrop();"` of the dropzone makes the dropzone invisible again. But when the user just cancels the dragging (he does not release the panel over the dropzone) the dropzone is still visible.

For this I tried `onmouseup="stopDragDrop();"` on the panel but this causes the bean not to be called because the javascript function called earlier. This makes the dropzone invisible and therefore there is no action event anymore.

How can I make my dropzone invisible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I.e. why does the dropzone need to be invisible? If you just want to highlight it during dragging then you can use `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` on the panel. You should avoid the `rendered` attribute in this case, use something like `display: none`.

Comment: Its just about styling. The user should not always see the dropzone, just when he wants to delete something. And when I use the panel with `onmouseenter` the the user must know where the panel is so and this is not comfortable

Comment: Well, the user should know where is he going to drag things before he starts dragging them, shouldn't he? Anyway, can't you keep it as it is and instead of trying to call the bean simply use jQuery to switch between `display: block` and `display: none`?

Comment: I think it doesnt matter why I would do it like that. All functions on the dropzone are not really helpful for me, also not with jQuery because the dropzone is below the panel and if the user just releases the dragged item without dragging it over the dropzone, the dropzone `onmouseout` function would never be called

Comment: I meant `onmouseup`, as it is in your example, but you wouldn't call `stopDragDrop` and instead use jQuery to hide the panel.

Comment: The hiding of the dropzone also works well with jQuery and its `hide` function but the problem is the same. The `onmouseup` function seems to be called always before the bean method of the dropzone. So as I mentioned in the question the dropzone would disappear correctly but this happens before the bean method `#{bean.processDrop}` is called